# Why my scene is different than my game? I should be able to see my player and map but I don't

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to learn Unity making a base map with a player.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yesterday, when I was pressing the play button I was able to test the game correctly, but today it stopped working, and as far as I know/remember I didn't change anything...

This is what I can see in game tab:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

How can I show in game tab what I see in scene? I mean the map and the player. I can only see the Canvas right now...

Comment: Are there multiple cameras in your scene?

Comment: no, only "Main camera" I was trying to add a Cinemachine but I deleted it to check if that was the problem so right now I only have 1 camera

Comment: Have you checked the sorting layers and in general the layers? Is your camera rendering all layers?

Comment: My sorting layers are: Default, Ground, Player, Interiors... I didn't touch sorting layers since last time was working, so I guess sorting layers are ok. I'm not sure how to check if my camera is rendering all layers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, `Z` value in MainCamera got reset:

[image]

After setting back to  -10 it worked again